# MVC Bundle - Include css less variables from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, bundle

As the title says - I am using LessBundle in my BundleConfig to bundle all my less files together.

I will have N number of user defined themes on my site (restricted to specific variables, like background-color).

I want to be able to create a less file containing these variables from the database that can then be bundled with my other less files.

Another important part is that the less file should have cache busting for when the user updates a theme.

What is the best direction to go with this?

Comment: I think there isn't a way to do what you want because LESS files can't generate CSS file on runtime. So how do you want to update CSS files when user changed values ? I think the best way is to store the design preferences of the user in their profile and apply their preferences to your website theme according to who is connected. And when the user updates his values, just update his profile and re-apply the theme according to his changes.

Comment: @D4rkTiger Without doing some kind of inline css with a razor call, how would you propose doing that? There has to be some way of customizing the bundler to add dynamic css to a bundle.

Comment: I discover a new thing thnaks to you ^^. I have see an article explained you can create a bundle dynamically and when I see the parameter in constructor, I've seen that you can specify a virtual path. So I think you can create an handler answer to a specific virtualPath in your application which return as response your user's CSS generated from template or another. It is my first idea after discovering the dynamic bundling

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle css bundles as far as i know one at runtime and one dynamically.  I wouldn't go dynamically unless you absolutely had to as this can cause some pitfalls later on in the application.

If you are looking for themes a simple xml config file that has values you can write to can be stored in the DB and pulled out of the DB to read and used in the system may be better suited.

I would then based off those values load the appropriate css folder and use same css naming conventions in each folder.

example i have a light and a dark theme 0 and 1, my xml file is set to 1 so everytime i goto load a view i quickly check that to see if it's 1 or 0 then set `ViewBag.cssfolder = "dark";`

i then on each view when i load my css i will do the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/" + @viewBag.cssfolder + "/file.css")%>" />
```

there might be a better way to do this but this will be a quick answer to hopefully get you on your way.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that I would have to define all of my themes beforehand. I'm looking for a solution wherein the theme can be changed during run-time without the need to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

LessCss comes with a [command-line tool](http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html):

> Global Variable
>
> lessc --global-var="my-background=red" This option defines a variable
>   that can be referenced by the file. Effectively the declaration is put
>   at the top of your base Less file, meaning it can be used but it also
>   can be overridden if this variable is defined in the file.
>
> Modify Variable
>
> lessc --modify-var="my-background=red" As opposed to the global
>   variable option, this puts the declaration at the end of your base
>   file, meaning it will override anything defined in your Less file.
>
> URL Arguments
>
> lessc --url-args="cache726357" This option allows you to specify a
>   argument to go on to every URL. This may be used for cache-busting for
>   instance.

You can integrate this tool into your build process with MSBuild or run it as a command-line build option. I'm sure you can program a way to pass the config values to this tool during the build. Good luck!

Comment: The issue with this, is that it has to be done at compile time. I'm looking for something that serves dynamic CSS (assumption at run-time). If i had to update a theme I would have to recompile with this solution, in which case I might as well just manually drop css files into the project.

Comment: @ByronCobb you can call that command line from anywhere, it doesn't have to be MSBuild. Call it from within your business class when you update a theme. It's the command line, don't be afraid of it.